# When I try to access my https website on android devices I am always prompted, why?

Tags: android, ssl, https

I used this code to force an https redirect... could this be the culprit?

[image]

Scenarios include:

LG3 (You will have to change your lock pattern - continue, cancel) 
Nexus 4 (No certificates found - install, cancel)
LG-LS720 (No certificates found - install, cancel)

Answer (score 0):

**If by prompted you mean "My browser ask me for a certificate" :**

SSLVerifyClient optional mean that the CLIENT may present a certificate. Do you really want that ? By default this directive is "none" which mean only the SERVER present a certificate.

Except if you really know what you are doing, you can remove the lines SSLRequireSSL to SSLOptions

You said you use this code to do a http->https redirect so I think you misunderstook the directive SSLRequireSSL. So do a redirect you need listen on the port 80 (http) and return a redirect. For example :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName mysite.example.com
   DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/htdocs 
   Redirect permanent / https://mysite.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/22838/is-a-forced-rewrite-from-http-to-https-secure-what-does-sslrequiressl-add

**If by prompted you mean "My browser tell me the certificate is not valid" :**

If you test your website with https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ and see "The certificate chain on your server is incomplete" It's mean you failed to provide the correct certification chain. So your desktop broswer has the correct intermediate certificate in his cache (so he can "forgive" your mistake), but not your mobile browser (so he can't check the validity of the certificate).

Comment: Hello Tom, thanks for your response, the result was a C primarily being vulnerable to a "POODLE" attack. I think I have tried to fix this before, I am using webmin, I think it was a pain but I will see what I can do to get the encryption up to par.